# Spinning iphone based on ground

Tags: iphone

I am rotate iphone based on the ground

But the UIAcceleration values of (x&y&z) are same . Can you tell me exactly what happens here ?

Also i want know how to its  calculate UIAcceleration values of(x&y&z) ?

I am really interested to work with UIAcceleration values.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIAcceleration value can only detect acceleration *relative to the orientation of the device*.

By rotating the iPhone, in its frame of reference there is a *constant* gravity force (along the *z* axis) and a *constant* centrifugal force (on the *xy*-plane), so the UIAcceleration will not change.

You cannot distinguish acceleration due to gravity or linear acceleration or rotation by the accelerometer. You need other devices e.g. the compass (magnetometer) to detect a rotational change.